# How do I use the zoo package to convert Year.Quarter to a date?

Tags: date, lubridate, zoo

My column with my date variables look like "2022.Q2"
I would like to convert this into a numeric date using as.yearqtr but I keep getting an error on the format.
as.Date(as.yearqtr(Year, format = "%y.%Q"))
that's what I'm running. What am I doing wrong?
I would like it to read it as a date and output 2022 Q2 or 2022-04

Answer (score 0):

Just a small adjustment to `format` necessary:

```r
library(zoo)

x <- "2022.Q2"

as.yearqtr(x, format = "%Y.Q%q") 
#' "2022 Q2"

as.yearqtr(x, format = "%Y.Q%q") |> as.POSIXct() |> format("%Y-%m") 
#' "2022-04"
```